# Is there a way to commit changes to multiple branches without stashing?

Tags: git

Often I have a bunch of changes in my working copy that I would like to commit to different new branches, like this:

```
    o   third
  o |   second
o | |   first
| | |
\ | /
  o     base
```

What I do then is:

- (on the "base" branch)
- create the first branch
- stage and commit a part of the changes
- stash the rest of the changes
- check out the base branch
- apply the stash
- create the second branch
- stage and commit the next part of the changes
- stash the rest of the changes
- ...

Git wouldn't just let me check out the base branch without stashing the rest of the changes, even though it wouldn't (and I think cannot) create a conflict.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Look at the `git cherry-pick` command, which allows you to selectively copy commits from the base to each new branch.

Comment: Please satisfy our curiosity as to why you’re using this unusual workflow.

Comment: Is it unusual? I come across it all the time when I implement features together but want them tested/cherry-picked as separate features, for example server-side webservice and client-side Javascript GUI code in a web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write:

```
$ git checkout -b new_branch base
```

git will create a new branch starting from base and keep your local changes. It's equivalent to

```
$ git stash
$ git branch new_branch base
$ git checkout new_branch 
$ git stash apply
```

So your workflow now becomes:

```
$ git checkout -b first master
$ git add -p; git commit         # commit changes for first branch
$ git checkout -b second master
$ git add -p; git commit         # commit changes for second branch
# etc
```

Comment: Then the three would be based on each other, which I don't want. I updated the question with a drawing.

Comment: @AndreKR, let me test if `git checkout -b another_branch base_branch` would work or not, then I'll update/delete the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you wrote that you don’t expect merge conflicts. The test with `git checkout` is more conservative: do the *originals* (that is, as committed) of the locally modified files in the current and destination branches differ at all?

After running the following to create the `first` branch

```
$ git checkout -b first

$ edit ..

$ git add -p .

$ git commit -m first
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

you are likely seeing an error similar to

```
$ git checkout base
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by
checkout:
        [files ..]
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

when attempting to switch back to `base`.

The `--merge` option to `git checkout` works in this sort of situation.

> `-m`
> `--merge`
>
> When switching branches, if you have local modifications to one or more files that are different between the current branch and the branch to which you are switching, the command refuses to switch branches in order to preserve your modifications in context. However, with this option, a three-way merge between the current branch, your working tree contents, and the new branch is done, and you will be on the new branch.
>
> When a merge conflict happens, the index entries for conflicting paths are left unmerged, and you need to resolve the conflicts and mark the resolved paths with `git add` (or `git rm` if the merge should result in deletion of the path).

Running `git checkout -m base` will get you back where you started—but perhaps further than you want. You will be on the `base` branch with all your edits rather than only the changes intended for `second` and `third`. For each commit, you will need to discard the changes for the other two branches as opposed to progressively whittling down your changes.